# Reactjs doesn't immediately update the assigned value when useState is used

Tags: reactjs, asynchronous, react-hooks, use-state

**Reactjs** does not update the new value when I use **usestate** hook: Look at this example:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Dictionary = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("Bob");

  useEffect(() => {
    updateName();
  }, []);

  const updateName = () => {
    setName("John");
    console.log("name:", name); // prints "Bob"
    setName(myName => "John");
    console.log("name:", name); // prints "Bob"
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Dictionary</h2>
    </>
  );
};
```

I have tried to make use of promises but I don't get a solution either.

```js
const updateName = async () => {
    await uName("John");
    console.log(name); // "Bob"
  };

  const uName = (nam) => {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
      setName(nam);
      res();
    });
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your code as:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const Dictionary = () => {
  const [name, setName] = useState("Bob");

  useEffect(() => {
    updateName();
  }, []);


  useEffect(() => {
    /* Use this useEffect to perform actions when name get updated. */
    console.log(name);
  }, [name]);

  const updateName = () => {
    setName("John");
    console.log("name:", name); // prints "Bob"
    setName(myName => "John");
    console.log("name:", name); // prints "Bob"
  };

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Dictionary</h2>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Yes, this was my solution. The problem is that I am creating an application using the setInterval method and audio API. I usually use many **UseEFfect()** Hooks and obtain as a result a spaghetti code.

Comment: @Ricky why can't you let it run to completion and just get updated values next run?

Answer (score 1):

React is still Javascript, and it only updates values on the next run.

See commented code below:

```
  const updateName = () => {
    setName("John");        // Updates the name. Will be "John" on the next render
    console.log("name:", name); // Should print "Bob"
    setName(myName => "John");  // Will run `myName => "John"` on the next render. 
    console.log("name:", name); // Should print "Bob"
  };
```

When you run `set` hooks, it marks the value as updated and triggers a new render as soon as this `render` is done.

You can't change the update the value of state mid-render, as the code at the top of the `render()` would have run with the old value.

Directly from a [the React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html):

> component schedules a UI update by calling setState() [...] Thanks to the setState() call, React knows the state has changed, and calls the render() method again to learn what should be on the screen